# I want to add parent product to cart using child product id, it's configurable options in magento 2.1

Tags: magento2, product, configurable-product

I want to add parent product to cart using child product id, it's configurable options in.
Do like this

Get child id & using child id we can get parent product id.

Load the Configurable Attributes names of a product with it's(parent id). Then use In

> $childid='15';$rep=
>   $obj->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository');
>   $childObj=$rep->getById($childid);
>   $aray[$att['attribute_id']]=$childObj->getData($attr->getDat‌​a('attribute_code'))‌​;
>   now we have only child product configurableoptions
>   $params2=array();$params2['selected_configurable_option'] =
>   $childid;$params2['super_attribute'] = $aray;$params2['qty'] = 1;
>   $this->cart->addProduct($parentid,$params2); $this->cart->save();

**Note :** Added the content from the comments to clear information

Comment: do like this*Get child id & using child id we can get parent product id.*Load the Configurable Attributes names of a product with it's(parent id).*then use In $childid='15';$rep= $obj->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository');
$childObj=$rep->getById($childid);
$aray[$att['attribute_id']]=$childObj->getData($attr->getData('attribute_code')); now we have only child product configurableoptions $params2=array();$params2['selected_configurable_option'] = $childid;$params2['super_attribute'] = $aray;$params2['qty'] = 1;
$this->cart->addProduct($parentid,$params2);  $this->cart->save();

Comment: if you include the details in question instead of comment , there will be chances of getting solution.....

Comment: Hi vickey, I added the solution which I got..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got solution from below code and it's worked for me..

```
  $childid='15';

    $obj= \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

    $rep= $obj->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository'); 

    $childObj=$rep->getById($childid); 

    $aray[$att['attribute_id']]=$childObj->getData($attr->getDat‌​a('attribute_code'))‌​; 

    //now we have only child product configurableoptions 

    $params2=array();

    $params2['selected_configurable_option']=$childid;

    $params2['super_attribute'] = $aray;

    $params2['qty'] = 1; 

    $this->cart->addProduct($parentid,$params2); 

    $this->cart->save();
```

Comment: its not worked, please check the solution again